# An Issue With Writing In A File In C#

Tags: c#, file

I developed a simple program that asks the user if he wants to add a new record to a file or display all the records contained in the file, but I seem to have a problem in writing to the file. The file is created but still nothing is written in it. The reading function works fine since I wrote something in the file to see if it works.

Here is the code...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace F01
{
    class Program
    {
        static int ID;
        static String Name;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileStream MyFiler = new FileStream("MyFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            StreamReader FileReader = new StreamReader(MyFiler);
            StreamWriter FileWriter = new StreamWriter(MyFiler);
            Console.WriteLine("Please Select One Of The Following Options... ");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Enter A New Record In The File.");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Read All The Records From The File.");
            int Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (Choice == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter The ID: ");
                ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                FileWriter.WriteLine(ID);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter The Name: ");
                Name = Console.ReadLine();
                FileWriter.WriteLine(Name);
            }

            else if (Choice == 2)
            {
                FileWriter.Close();
                String fileText = File.ReadAllText("MyFile.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i < fileText.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(fileText[i]);
                }
            }
            FileReader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use `using`. You are not closing your writer.

Comment: and `FileStream.Flush()` could help too.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278(v=vs.110).aspx  That shows how to use the File object to append to a file more efficiently, and proper use of the "using" statement.  (Using the "using" statement is a best practice in cases like this, where you may forget to close a file reference).  Please check out that article and see if you can apply the principles to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not closing the writer in the only situation in which you're using it - "choice 1". Basically the data is being buffered, and lost when the process exits because you haven't closed the writer.

I would *strongly* advise you to:

- Only open the file when you need to
- Use local variables instead of class variables unless you *need* them in other methods
- Use the `File` static methods to make all of this easier
- Use `using` statements to clean up resources at the end of them (if you need a writer or a stream at all, that is...)
- Break your code up into methods for separate operations
- Name your variables in `camelCase` rather than `PascalCase`
- Print your file a *line* at a time rather than a *letter* at a time

So for example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    const string FileName = "MyFile.txt";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please Select One Of The Following Options... ");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Enter A New Record In The File.");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Read All The Records From The File.");
        int choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                AddEntry();
                break;
            case 2:
                ReadFile();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, that's not a valid option");
                break;
        }
   }

   static void AddEntry()
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Enter the ID:");
       int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       Console.WriteLine("Enter the name:");
       string name = Console.ReadLine();
       File.AppendAllLines(FileName, new[] { id.ToString(), name });
   }

   static void ReadFile()
   {
       foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(FileName))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(line);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your `MyFiler` which is a `FileStream` type which is `IDisposable` type is not wrapped in `using` statement, nor do you call `.Dispose()` manually.  Same for your readers (which are also disposable types).  This can lead to this type of behavior...

Try the follwing:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace F01
{
    class Program
    {
        static int ID;
        static String Name;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(FileStream MyFiler = new FileStream("MyFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using(StreamReader FileReader = new StreamReader(MyFiler))
                {
                    using(StreamWriter FileWriter = new StreamWriter(MyFiler))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Select One Of The Following Options... ");
                        Console.WriteLine("1. Enter A New Record In The File.");
                        Console.WriteLine("2. Read All The Records From The File.");
                        int Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        if (Choice == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter The ID: ");
                            ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            FileWriter.WriteLine(ID);
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter The Name: ");
                            Name = Console.ReadLine();
                            FileWriter.WriteLine(Name);
                        }

                        else if (Choice == 2)
                        {
                            FileWriter.Close();
                            String fileText = File.ReadAllText("MyFile.txt");
                            for (int i = 0; i < fileText.Length; i++)
                            {
                                Console.Write(fileText[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        FileReader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```